# putting php array into html code

Tags: php

I use to do this really easily with a template php system, called smarty. I currently am not able smarty so I have to do it manually but I have completely forgotten how and what is possible....

```
                <? foreach ($searchresults as $row) { ?>
                    <tr class="tableRows">
                        <td><img style="cursor: pointer;" src="img/expand.png" id="1" alt="hidden" onclick="changeSign()" /></td>
                        <td><a href="#"><?  echo $row[0]; ?></a></td>
                        <td><? echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                        <td><?  echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                        <td><?  echo $row[3]; ?></td>
                        <td><?  echo $row[4]; ?></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteBtn" /></td>
                    </tr>
                <? } ?>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
        <?php } ?>
```

This doesn't work. Wondering how can I make it work. Basically I want to put the arrays data into the rows.

( I forgot echo at the start of the question, I already did try it and I have updated it as such but is still not working)

The issue is nothing is being put out, but the array contains data for sure as when I do a var_dump it spits out:

```
array(10) { [0]=> string(4) "3344" ["purchaseNo"]=> string(4) "3344" [1]=> string(10) "2013-03-31" ["dateCreated"]=> string(10) "2013-03-31" [2]=> string(4) "John" ["Name"]=> string(4) "John" [3]=> string(5) "Mold1" ["mouldName"]=> string(5) "Mold1" [4]=> NULL ["courierName"]=> NULL }
```

Comment: try echo before $row[1]

Comment: *"This doesn't work."* This is useless as diagnostic information. *How* doesn't it work?

Comment: I added echo I forgot, I had it but was trying something else, it still doesn't echo out anything.

Comment: try print_r($searchresults ) to check your array is not empty

Comment: It's not empty. I just posted out what var_dump spits out...also I did print_r and it's populated

Comment: -1 for editing the question to invalidate basically every answer here.

Comment: That was just a mistake, I posted the old version of the code, also it still doesn't work. So it's not solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try echo before $row[1] `<?php echo $row[1]; ?>`

So your answer is:

```
<? foreach ($searchresults as $row) { ?>
                        <tr class="tableRows">
                            <td><img style="cursor: pointer;" src="img/expand.png" id="1" alt="hidden" onclick="changeSign()" /></td>
                            <td><a href="#"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></a></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
                            <td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteBtn" /></td>
                        </tr>

   <? } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you :) That works some what, few things I need to fix myself but that's perfect thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Put `echo $row[i]` instead of `$row[i]` only

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with the variable. You need to output it:

```
<td><?= $row[1] ?></td>
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

you need to `echo` your variables
something like

```
    <? foreach ($searchresults as $row) { ?>
                    <tr class="tableRows">
                        <td><img style="cursor: pointer;" src="img/expand.png" id="1" alt="hidden" onclick="changeSign()" /></td>
                        <td><a href="#"><? echo $row[0]; ?></a></td>
                        <td><? echo $row[1]; ?></td>
                        <td><? echo $row[2]; ?></td>
                        <td><? echo $row[3]; ?></td>
                        <td><? echo $row[4]; ?></td>
                        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteBtn" /></td>
                    </tr>

  <? } ?>
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

you have to use `echo` for displaying any variable or text. or use

`echo "<pre>"; print_r($row); echo "</pre>";` for displaying whole array

Answer (score 0):

Try this, hope it'll work

```
<?php 
      foreach ($searchresults as $row)
      { ?>
         <tr class="tableRows">
             <td><img style="cursor: pointer;" src="img/expand.png" id="1" alt="hidden" onclick="changeSign()" /></td>
             <td><a href="#"><?php echo $row[0]; ?></a></td>
             <td><?php echo $row[1]; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row[2]; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row[3]; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $row[4]; ?></td>
             <td><input type="button" value="Delete" class="deleteBtn" /></td>
          </tr>

 <?php } ?>
```